# How can I add the attributes of 2 classes using method overloading?

Tags: python

1.I really have 2 questions. First I am getting unexpected output of

> `None None`

from my last line of code

2. For the harder question I need to use method overloading to add the cost of these two item objects.
   I first prompt the user for item 1 asking for its name, price then quantity. I then multiply the price and the quantity to get that items total.

I repeat this for the second item
I then want to display the two items and there separate total as well as the combined total. It should look like this

```
TOTAL COST
Apple 3 @ $2 = $6
Balls 4 @ $4 = $16

Total: $22
```

I'm getting this instead

```
TOTAL COST

x 3 @ $2 = $6
y 6 @ $4 = $24
None None
```

I don't know where the "None None" is coming from or how to remove it without the item info getting removed and I don't know how to combine the cost using overloading. I have what looks like a solution in the **add** method here with my code

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name = 'none', price = 0, quantity = 0):
        self.item_name = name
        self.item_price = price
        self.item_quantity = quantity
        self.total = price * quantity

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.total + other.total


    def print_item_cost(self):
        return print('{} {} @ ${} = ${}'.format(self.item_name,
                                              self.item_price,
                                              self.item_quantity,
                                              self.total))

#Grab first item
print('Item 1')
name_1 = input('Enter the item name: ')
price_1 = int(input('Enter the item price: '))
qty_1 = int(input('Enter the item quantity: '))
item_1 = Item(name_1, price_1, qty_1)

#Grab second item
print('\nItem 2')
name_2 = input('Enter the item name: ')
price_2 = int(input('Enter the item price: '))
qty_2 = int(input('Enter the item quantity: '))
item_2 = Item(name_2, price_2, qty_2)


#Output cost
print('\n\nTOTAL COST')
print(item_1.print_item_cost(), item_2.print_item_cost())
```

Comment: I wouldn't overload `__add__` here. Addition should, when possible, be *closed*, that is, if I add an `a` and an `a`, I should get back another `a`, not a `b`. Define a separate function like `total_price` that takes two (or more) `Item` objects and returns their total price.

Comment: Save `__add__` for something like `Item('apple', 2, 3) + Item('apple', 1, 5) == Item('apple', 11/8, 8)`, which says buying 3 apples at $2 each and 5 apples at $1 each (for a total of $11) is the same as buying 8 apples for an average price of $1.375 (== 11/8).

Answer (score 2):

1) `print` returns None. Therefore, you should change `print_item_cost` to

```
def print_item_cost(self):
        return '{} {} @ ${} = ${}'.format(self.item_name,
                                              self.item_price,
                                              self.item_quantity,
                                              self.total)
```

Comment: This is strange. I removed  the `print` and it removed the 'None None' but it also removed the printed items info. Which I need displayed, so I put the 'print' back and now it works? It shows                                                                                              `ball 2 @ $4 = $8
card 3 @ $2 = $6` without the 'None None'